# Table heading function thought Manipulate output

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, list-manipulation

```
Clear[Rth, Phex];Rth[tmax_, tin_, qmax_] := N[(tmax - tin)/qmax];Dynamic[Manipulate[Panel[Column[{"Rth:", Style[Rth[tmax, tin, qmax], Red, Bold, 14]
 }, Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, FrameStyle -> Red],"Calculated Values :"],Text[Style["Calculator", 20, Background -> LightBlue, 
FontWeight -> Bold]],Delimiter,{{tmax, 80, "Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},{{qmax, 5000, "Load (W): "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},{{tin, 50, "Inlet Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},{{tamb, 25, "Ambient air Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},{{m, 1.0, "Flow Rate : "}, {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2},ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, FieldSize -> 5},Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}], Background -> Blue],LabelStyle -> {20}, ContentSize -> 500, Frame -> True,TrackedSymbols :> All,Frame -> True, FrameMargins -> Automatic]]
```

In the above code, we get the output as a calculated value of Rth (0.006 by default). This value will change as per the user inputs.

I also have one table given below:

```
CP =  TableForm[{{0.0078, 0.0066, 0.0088, 0.0082, 0.0078},{0.0058, 0.0049, 0.0073, 0.0067, 0.006},{0.0054, 0.0046, 0.0068, 0.0065, 0.0056},{0.0051, 0.0041, 0.006, 0.006, 0.0051}},TableHeadings -> {{"0.5 GPM", "1.0 GPM", "1.5 GPM", 
 "2.0 GPM"}, {"CP-1000", "CP-1001", "CP-1002", "CP-1003", 
 "CP-1004"}}]
```

Now I want to display one more output beside the calculated value, which will be the table's heading. I have Rth 0.006 as the computed value at 1 GPM in the default case. Now I want to make logic such that the calculated value goes to the table and sees where this value is matched. And display the column heading.

Example: Rth =0.006 at 1GPM (Row). The output will be CP-1004 (2nd row & 5th column).
And if the output is not matched with the table value, it should show the nearest smaller value column heading name.

Like: The calculated value of Rth= 0.005 (For different user input), The closest smaller value at 1 GMP Row is 0.0049. At that condition, the Column heading CP-1001 will be displayed as output.

The logic should work the same if the user changes GPM or Row values like 0.5,1.5,2 GPM.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this logic?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please improve the title of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty routine to get the heading. It uses the table CP:

Input: rth== calculated value, m== flow rate

```
getHeading[rth_, m_] := Module[{pos, col},
  pos = Position[ToExpression[StringTake[#, 3] & /@ CP[[2, 2, 1]]], 
    N[m]];
  col = Position[CP[[1, pos[[1, 1]]]], 
     Nearest[CP[[1, pos[[1, 1]]]], rth][[1]]][[1, 1]];
  CP[[2, 2, 2, col]]
  ]
```

Here is an example:

```
getHeading[0.0052, 1.5]
(*"CP-1000"*)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel... But How I could embed this code into my code.

Comment: E.g.: `Row[{Panel[
   Column[{"Rth:", Style[tmp = Rth[tmax, tin, qmax], Red, Bold, 14]}, 
    Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, FrameStyle -> Red], 
   "Calculated Values :"], getHeading[tmp, m]}]`

Comment: Thank you So much for your Support... But I need the nearest as well as smallest value column heading. If there is no value smaller than the calculated one. in that case, can I display a massage like "Not found in Table"?

Comment: Simply change "Neareast" to "Min"

Comment: @ Daniel Can I get your email address?

Comment: I used to share my address freely. In the end I had to get a new address because I got so much spam mail.

Comment: I have a project and I need your help to execute it.

Comment: Why can you not post your question here?

Comment: I Changed "Nearest" to "Min" As you asked me to do.. But it's not working.

Comment: Could you please modify the getHeading function for Min.?

Comment: getMin[m_] := Module[{pos},
   pos = Position[ToExpression[StringTake[#, 3] & /@ CP[[2, 2, 1]]], 
      N[m]][[1]];
   Min[CP[[1, pos]]]];

Comment: In the getHeading function, I changed "Nearest" to "Min". why it is not working in getHeading function? I want the Coulum heading which is the closest minimum to the Rth value.

Comment: You also need to change the parameters to the correct ones for "Min". Simply use "getMin" I posted above.

Comment: I don't know how to do that... Daniel, can we build a function that takes row and column headings as input argument and return the corresponding cell values? Like in Table CP.  getValueCP[Row_Heading, Column_Heading]

Comment: I think you should make an effort to learn the mathematica language.  Here is a function that gets the value from row and column headings: `getValue[row_, col_] := CP[[1, Position[CP[[2, 2, 1]], "1.5 GPM"][[1]],
    Position[CP[[2, 2, 2]], "CP-1001"][[1]]]][[1, 1]]`and the is an example: `getValue["1.5 GPM", "CP-1001"]`

Comment: Yes, you are right I need to give more time to learning. I thought it would be easy but it's not that much. But you helped me a lot still my problem same, I don't know what to do now.

Comment: This getValue Function gives me value only for 1.5 GPM & CP-1001, What if I want to know others as well.

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct function: `getValue[row_, col_] := 
 CP[[1, Position[CP[[2, 2, 1]], row][[1]], 
    Position[CP[[2, 2, 2]], col][[1]]]][[1, 1]]`

Comment: Thanks, Daniel... Now it's working fine.

Comment: Deniel, I want to call that function this way: getValue["m GPM", "getHeading[ rth,m]"].... Can we call this function this way?

Comment: Should work, simply try it out.

Comment: Tried but it's not working...

Comment: Try e.g.: `getValue["1.5 GPM", getHeading[0.0052, 1.5]]`  This gives 0.0054. I think your mistake are the quotation marks around getHeading[..]. If you really want to give  "getHeading[ rth,m]" as a string, you need to wrap ToExpression around it.

Comment: ToExpression function not working here I used to like that:  ToExpression["m GPM"]. GetHeading Function working fine... Can you tell how to build a function that gives the ROW heading as output? Like: getRowHeading[m_] = {Function body}....I tried to modify getHeading function but failed.

Comment: `getValue["1.5 GPM", ToExpression["getHeading[0.0052,1.5]"]]`is working

Comment: In the first term, if I put ToExpression["m GPM"] it should also work.... Where m= {0.5 GPM, 1GPM,  1.5 GPM, 2.0 GPM}, basically if user changer the "m" value it should display the value of corresponding row and column. for 2nd term its working but the first term have issue.

Comment: I think it is time that you do something yourself.

Comment: Agree with you and I am doing my best... And thanks for all your support.

Comment: I tried to build this function..."getRow[m_] := CP[[2, 2, 1, m]]" with that I am able to get the row heading by giving the position of the row as an argument. What modification would you suggest to get row heading by giving the value of them? Like 0.5,1,1.5,2

Comment: `getRow[m_] := 
  CP[[Sequence @@ 
     Position[CP, ToString[NumberForm[m, {2, 1}]] <> " GPM"][[1]]]];` Note that you make things more complicated than necessary by working with CP that includes "TableForm" it is easier to work with a bare table without headings.

Comment: Thanks Daniel... Its working fine. Yes, I think you are right Handling Bare Table is much easier than TableForm... I will try with a bare table also...